Get second run font size using Apache POI
I have a Word document, in that we have a variables like @DATE. When we read it as XWPFRun from XWPFParagraph, we get two runs 1. "@" and 2. "DATE.
How can I get the font size of "DATE" (2nd run)? I am getting first run "@" font size, but null for second run "DATE"
for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
   for(XWPFRun r1 : p.getRuns()){
      iFontSize = r1.getFontSizeAsDouble()
   } 
}

So here, for the second run "DATE", getFontSizeAsDouble returns null.

The API documentation of XWPFRun.getFontSizeAsDouble states:

Returns:
value representing the font size (can be null if size not set)

If font size not set, then default font size is used.
Default font size may be stored in run properties of paragraph style. The ID of the paragraph style can be got via XWPFParagraph.getStyleID. Then the style itself can be got via XWPFStyles.getStyle. If there is not a paragraph style assigned directly then the paragraph style with name "Normal" get used. XWPFStyles.getStyleWithName can be used to find this style. Unfortunately the XWPFStyle does not provide a method to get the font size from run properties. So a method must be created. Following got adopted from XWPFDefaultRunStyle.getFontSizeAsDouble:
 ... Double getFontSizeAsDouble(XWPFStyle style) {
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTRPr rPr = style.getCTStyle().getRPr();
  if (rPr != null && rPr.sizeOfSzArray() > 0) {
   java.math.BigDecimal bDSize = java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(
    org.apache.poi.util.Units.toPoints(
     org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.POIXMLUnits.parseLength(rPr.getSzArray(0).xgetVal())))
     .divide(java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(4), 1, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
   return bDSize == null ? null : bDSize.doubleValue();
  }
  return null;
 }

If the default font is not stored in in run properties of paragraph style, then it may be stored in document styles.
XWPFDocument.getStyles -> XWPFStyles.getDefaultRunStyle -> XWPFDefaultRunStyle.getFontSizeAsDouble.
If neither default run style nor document styles are present, then I would assume standard font Calibri in size 11.
...
Double dFontSize;
XWPFTableCell cell ...
...

 for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
  for(XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
   System.out.println(run);
   dFontSize = run.getFontSizeAsDouble(); // direct styled run properties
   if (dFontSize == null) {
    XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();
    if (styles != null) {
     if (paragraph.getStyleID() != null) {
      XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyle(paragraph.getStyleID());
      if (style != null) {
       dFontSize = getFontSizeAsDouble(style); // styled by paragraph style run properties
      }
     }
     if (dFontSize == null) {
      XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyleWithName("Normal");
      if (style != null) {
       dFontSize = getFontSizeAsDouble(style); // styled by "Normal" paragraph style run properties
      }
     }
     if (dFontSize == null) {
      XWPFDefaultRunStyle defaultRunStyle = styles.getDefaultRunStyle();
      if (defaultRunStyle != null) {
       dFontSize = defaultRunStyle.getFontSizeAsDouble(); // styled by default run style run properties
      }
     }
    }
    if (dFontSize == null) { // if all fails, then 11
      dFontSize = 11d;
    }
   }
   System.out.println(dFontSize);
  } 
 }

...


Hey Axel, I used part of your code and give null error , Please see here : https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/11gn , any help would be highly appreciated :-).

It needs to be Double dFontSize and not double dFontSize.

Hi Alex, Sorry, Yes I changed to Double and getFontSizeAsDouble() return "null" for run "DATE". getFontSizeAsDouble() return fontsize for "@" but not "DATE" which is second run, quite surprising.

A point to remember is that when you are iterating through the runs in a paragraph, you want to handle multiple runs with different properties, such as font size. In your case, you're only accessing the font size of the last run in each paragraph, which might not always be the one you're interested in.
Something like this can better solve your issue:
for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
    for(XWPFRun run : p.getRuns()) {
        if(run.text().contains("@DATE")) {
            double fontSize = run.getFontSizeAsDouble();
            System.out.println("Font size of '@DATE' run: " + fontSize);
            break; 
        }
    }
}

The above code will iterate through each run in a paragraph and check if the text within the run contains the pattern "@DATE". If a match is found, it retrieves the font size of that particular run. Using this approach ensures that you're getting the font size specifically for the "DATE" portion of "@DATE".

It won't work, because my run @DATE is split into two runs , @ and DATE. So i need font size of DATE which is 2nd run, while first run is "@" which i have fontsize = 10.

I see, you might need to handle cases where a variable like "@DATE" is split into separate runs. In this scenario, you might need to keep track of consecutive runs and concatenate them to reconstruct the variable.

Its already done, see the below code :
for (int runPos = found.getBeginRun(); runPos <= found.getEndRun(); runPos++) {
XWPFRun run = runs.get(runPos);
int iTextPos = run.getTextPosition();
if (iTextPos != -1) {
iTextPos = 0;
}
String strRunText = run.getText(iTextPos);
b.append(strRunText);
}

I think you are iterating through runs to reconstruct the text of a variable but you're not capturing the font size during this process. If you need to retrieve the font size of the "DATE" portion of the variable "@DATE", you can modify the loop to also capture the font size of the relevant run. https://justpaste.it/fe2su

yeah i tried and it given error : "{"Error":"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Double.doubleValue()" because the return value of
"org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun.getFontSizeAsDouble()" is null"}"

I found Solution using ASPOSE API. Since APACHE POI did not return font size for second run, ASPOSE API is power full then APACHE POI which returns any word in 200 pages of word document. Liked it.
Link to Solution : https://releases.aspose.com/words/java/16-8-0/
